# Как узнать кодировку столбца типа BLOB?

Tags: sql, oracle, кодировка

У меня есть таблица с колонкой типа BLOB, в ней лежит текст.

Как узнать в какой он кодировке?

PS А также подскажите, как изменить кодировку такой колонки?

Comment: В общем случае - никак, можно только гадать. `BLOB` - он не для текста, для текста есть `CLOB`.

Comment: На такой случай разумнее сделать колонку, в которой будет записана кодировка блоба. А так ищите вопросы "как определить кодировку (текстового) файла".

Comment: @Roman а в oracle можно отдельно задать кодировку таблицы, столбца ?

Comment: @Sergey почему файла?

Comment: @voipp Да потому что одно и тоже что в blob, что в файл. Там и там байты. Просто разные места хранения: в базе данных или в файловой системе. А вопрос ставится чаще всего о тексте в файле. Изредка просто о тексте без привязки к месту хранения.

Answer (score 2):

Кодировку текста в общем случае невозможно узнать, её знает только тот, кто этот текст сохранил. Например, латинская  `Ä` и кириллическая `Ф`. Мы знаем кодировку, в которой их хотим сохранить:

```
create table t1 as 
    select 1 id, convert ('Ä', 'we8iso8859p1') ch from dual union all
    select 2 id, convert ('Ф', 'cl8iso8859p5') ch from dual
/
```

Как теперь тот, кто читает эти данные может узнать, где `Ä`, а где `Ф`?

```
select id, dump (ch) from t1
/
        ID DUMP(CH)          
---------- ------------------
         1 Typ=1 Len=1: 196   
         2 Typ=1 Len=1: 196
```

---

> А так же подскажите, как изменить кодировку такой колонки?

Кодировку имеют, сама БД или сессия БД, и это распостраняется **на все символьные** колонки. Колонки с типом данных `BLOB` - это просто последовательность байтов, их кодировка не известна (см. пример выше).